# Why is the overflow not keeped on bottom?

Tags: jquery, overflow, chat, message

i'm making a website, which have a chat with messages.
So, i need that, the overflow of the chat messages container is keeped on bottom (like any chat), to the most recent message.

**This is the the HTML and the jquery code**

```
<div class="card-body overflow-auto" id="divChat" style="min-height:500px; max-height:500px;">
<script type="text/javascript">
    var scrollDiv = document.getElementById("divChat");
    scrollDiv.scrollTop = scrollDiv.scrollHeight;
    $(document).ready(function() {
        setInterval(function () {
            $('#divChat').load('./php/prendo-messaggi.php?id=<?php echo $idRichiesta; ?>')
        }, 500);
    });
</script>
```

"prendo-messaggi.php?id=.." is the php script which take the messages from the database's table.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The Jquery documentation state that you can add a callback function to the .load() method.

So a solution would be to check the .load returned new message, and if it returned a message you scrolldown your div.

Note that I don't know what your php script returns when there are no message, so you will have to figure out what enable the scrolldown.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(function () {
        $('#divChat').load('./php/prendo-messaggi.php?id=<?php echo $idRichiesta; ?>',
          function(responseText){
              if(responseText !== ''){
                scrollDiv.scrollTop = scrollDiv.scrollHeight;
              }
          }
        );
    }, 500);
});
```